# Ordered Field Extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm wondering if it's possible to order a field extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{x}]$ for $0<x\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that it is an ordered field with an ordered subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

It seemed that the ordering $$\leq_\sqrt{x}=\{(a+b\sqrt{x},c+d\sqrt{x}):a^2+c^2-2ac\leq x(b^2+d^2-2bd)\}$$ was promising, due to the algebraic manipulations $$a+b\sqrt{x}\leq c+d\sqrt{x}\iff a-c\leq\sqrt{x}(d-b)$$ $$\iff (a-c)^2\leq x(b-d)^2\iff a^2+c^2-2ac\leq x(b^2+d^2-2bd).$$ Despite this, if we use the canonical product structure $$(a+b\sqrt{x})(b+d\sqrt{x})=ab+bdx+(ad+bc)\sqrt{x}$$ it is not evident to me via algebra-crunching that orders are well-preserved under multiplication. Specifically, it isn't clear that for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{x}]$ we have that $a<b$ and $c<d$ imply $ac<bd$. Is this the case, and if not is there an ordereing we can explicitly define that makes a field extension like this ordered with $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield?

**Edit**

More specifically, suppose we have (a-priori) the ordered field $\mathbb{Q}=\langle\mathbb{Q},+,-,\times,\div,\leq\rangle$, and we wish to totally order the field extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\langle\mathbb{Q},+_{\sqrt{2}},-_{\sqrt{2}},\times_{\sqrt{2}},\div_{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2}\rangle$ with a total ordering $\leq_\sqrt{2}$ expressed in the language of ordered fields such that the subfield $\{a+b\sqrt{2}:b=0\}\subsetneq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ as an ordered field under the projection $\pi_0$ of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ onto its first factor, $$\pi_0(a+b\sqrt{2})=a.$$ What is an explicit formula for $\leq_\sqrt{2}$? Does the above formula for $\leq_\sqrt{x}$ work in the case that $x=2$?

Comment: I'm confused when you say $x \in \mathbb Q$.  Then $x$ is not an indeterminate, but a rational numbr?  So for example your question could be about $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}\;]$ ... why not use the ordinary real-number order on those?

Comment: Maybe you want the ordering to be definable in the language of rings?

Comment: @GEdgar I am, in reality, trying to totally order a splitting field extension of a nonstandard model of $\mathbb{Q}$ for some research I'm working on. I thought this question wasn't really research level, and I can extrapolate from the standard model case to the nonstandard model I'm working with on my own pretty easily. I would also like to do this without an a-priori construction of a nonstandard model of the $\mathbb{R}$ to work with, as the connection between those two things is what I'm trying to understand more deeply.

Comment: @Adayah I believe that should be sufficient, or even in the language of ordered fields.

Comment: That looks suspicious. If ${\leqslant} \in L$ is interpreted in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$, why not just take $\leqslant$ as the order? Otherwise, how is $\leqslant$ interpreted in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$? Or perhaps we somehow can compare rational numbers but can't directly compare elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ - in that case, how is the statement formalized?

Comment: @Adayah Not sure what you mean by suspect; if you don't find the question adequate feel free to downvote and move on. I use model theoretic phrasing because I have found it to be the fastest way to convey what I'm working with, however the methodologies I use in my research are more algebraic/analysis based. Nonstandard models of $\mathbb{R}$ are not well understood in terms of their analytical properties, and explicit algebraic extensions from a nonstandard model of $\mathbb{Q}$ are part of how I'm attempting to bridge the gap.

Comment: By "suspicious" I mean the problem looks trivially true, which suggests the formulation of it is not what you meant it to be. Rather that downvoting I'd rather try to find out what your intention was. Please refer to the edit I made to my last comment: is it so that we can compare rational numbers only and from that we're supposed to define an ordering of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$? If so, what is the precise formulation of the problem?

Comment: I would see it as something like: write a formula $\varphi(x, y)$ in the language $L_R \cup \{ \leqslant_{\mathbb{Q}} \}$ which defines an order on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, where $\leqslant_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]}$ (the interpretation of $\leqslant_{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$) is something that compares rational numbers but not all numbers. But what exactly is it? Of course, you may see it differently, but please be very precise, because the problem here is quite subtle.

Comment: @Adayah Thank you for the thoughts; I will consider them and add an edit to the question at some point tonight. It seems like you have the right problem in mind with $\leqslant_\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I'll do the specific case of $\sqrt{2}$.

I think it's best to do it through the set of positive numbers. Remember that in an ordered field $K$, for any $a\in K\setminus\{0\}$ either $a>0$ or $-a>0$. Moreover if $a>0$ and $b>0$ then $a+b>0$ and $ab>0$.

So we have the field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ with elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$. Now for elements of $\mathbb Q$ we know what numbers are positive (and indeed, it's not hard to show that we don't have a choice there). But what is the sign of $\sqrt{2}$? We have two choices: Either $\sqrt{2}>0$, then $-\sqrt{2}<0$, or $\sqrt{2}<0$, then $-\sqrt{2}>0$. But both choices are actually equivalent, as there's a field isomorphism exchanging $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$, and thus the choice just amounts to which of the two solutions of $x^2-2=0$ we call $\sqrt{2}$. Going with the usual convention, we choose $\sqrt{2}$ to be positive.

Now consider a general element $a + b\sqrt{2}$. We can concentrate on the case $b>0$ since for $b<0$ we simply get the opposite sign of $-a-b\sqrt{2}$ which again has a positive value of $b$. And for $b=0$ we just have a rational number, whose sign we already know.

Now we use the fact that with $b>0$ we also have $b^{-1}>0$, and multiply the above number with $b^{-1}$ (remember, multiplying with a positive number does not change the sign). Thus we get the condition $ab^{-1}+\sqrt{2}>0$.

If we write $c=ab^{-1}$, we therefore have to check for which values of $c$ we get $c+\sqrt{2}>0$.

Now if $c\ge 0$, then this is obviously positive. So we need to consider the case $c<0$. To more easily see the sign, let's define $d=-c$, so that $d>0$.

Now we can rewrite the condition as
$$0 < {\sqrt{2}-d} = \frac{(\sqrt{2}-d)(\sqrt{2}+d)}{\sqrt{2}+d}
= \frac{2-d^2}{\sqrt{2}+d}\quad.$$
The denominator is, again, clearly positive, so we get a positive number iff $d^2<2$.

Substituting everything back and combining the cases, we get for the case $b>0$ the condition:
$$a\ge 0 \lor a^2 < 2b^2$$
For $b<0$ we need the opposite condition for $-a$ and $-b$:
$$\lnot(-a\ge 0 \lor (-a)^2 < 2(-b)^2))$$
which can be rewritten as
$$a>0 \land a^2\ge 2b^2$$
The three cases ($b=0$, $b>0$ and $b<0$) can now of course be combined into a big expression, but I don't see an obvious way to simplify that.

Of course, as usual, you have $u>v$ iff $u-v>0$, which you can insert in the above conditions to make it even more complicated.

Your condition
$$a+b\sqrt{2} \le c+d\sqrt{2}\iff a^2+c^2-2ac\leq 2(b^2+d^2-2bd)$$
does not work, as it is symmetric under exchange of the two numbers. A concrete example that fails is $a=b=1, c=d=0$, which gives
$$1^2+9^2-2\cdot 1\cdot 0 = 1 \le 2 = 2(1^2+0^2-2\cdot 1 \cdot 0$$
so you'd get $1+\sqrt{2}\le 0$.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you.

Comment: @AlecRhea: You're welcome.